# Does a good faith violation have any consequence beyond 12 months after it happened?

Tags: united-states, trading

I read on [Fidelity](https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/trading-investing/trading/avoiding-cash-trading-violations):

> If you incur 3 good faith violations in a 12-month period in a cash account, your brokerage firm will restrict your account.

Does a good faith violation have any consequence beyond 12 months after it happened?

Comment: Do you mean: if you manage to "stay clean" for the 12 months after your first GFV is it **(a)** as though the original violation never happened... your slate is wiped clean; or **(b)** although your "violation count" is now back to zero (as far as the three-strikes leads-to-restriction rule is concerned), the fact you _had_ committed a GFV will stay on your record and might negatively impact your future relation with the broker?

Comment: @TripeHound exactly

Comment: "Exactly" **which**?

Answer (score 1):

The consequence of 3 good faith violations in 12 months is a 90 day account restriction.

Once you serve your time (account restricted for 90 days), I don't know if the 3 violations are wiped clean or whether the rolling count continues.  I would guess the latter in that when you incur a 4th violation, there's a 12 month look back and if it sees two previous violations, you're in back in trading hell again. Google for details.